Flutter input and display currency/price formatted from currency code
I am saving the currency-code and all I want is a textfield where the user can type in a price, formatted depending on the currency-code (without the currency-symbol) and then display the price depending on the currency-code.
But either I am too stupid or there is no "simple" solution for this. The currency should not be depending on any locale.
When in Germany, in the curency code is "USD", it should be displayed as:

$1,234.56

I've tried a lot of different things, but it's always messing up, due to some locale- behavior or other weird package behavior.
It should work for all different currency-codes.

You can try with intl package.
Here is a sample code.
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

String formattedCurrency(double number) {
    Locale locale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
    return NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(locale: locale.toString()).format(number);
}

